# Checking two condition in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

I am stuck with the problem, I know this might be simple but not getting any hit.

So the problem is I am getting two rows with the same ID having a different values.

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | UP |
| A | SUP |
| B | UP |
| B | SUP |
| C | SUP |
| D | UP |

So the scenario is if this Duplicate ID( A & B) comes I have to take precedence UP over  SUP and if Id comes normally without duplicate we take the value as it is.

The output should be:

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | UP |
| B | UP |
| C | SUP |
| D | UP |

Please help me
Thanks.

Comment: To help better answer a question, you need to provide what you tried, errors you got, and docs you looked up. Please consider improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `MAX()` does what you want:

```
select id, max(value)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Not sure max() will work with string.
Have solved the issue using row_number()

Comment: @PRANJULSINGH . . . Of course `max()` works with strings.